# Justify content not working properly on safari when element width is specified

Tags: css, safari, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm using Bootstrap's `d-flex justify-content-center` on a carousel. The carousel itself has a specified width. Everything is centering fine on Chrome and Firefox but in Safari the element goes over the right side (not centered).

I have tried using padding instead of width, the problem remains the same. I have tried fixed width (px), still the problem persists.

When removing the width of the element it is indeed centered but now the problem is that the element isn't my desired width.

```
   #carouselIndicators{
      height:70%;
      width: 70vw;
      border-radius: 15px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 15%;
      background-color: #f0f0f0;

    }
```

Here is the css code for the carousel itself.

So how do I actually center the element? Because right now it goes off the right side of the screen.

Comment: Have you tried centering it using auto margins instead ? Could be related to [Flexbug #11](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs#flexbug-11)

Comment: @Jake centering using margins worked. Still don't quite get why flex isnt working properly. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If your project is online could you send the URL so I that I could take a look at it ?